# Where to get Scopes dependencies for java for new Firebase Cloud Message API?

Tags: java, api, push, firebase-cloud-messaging

FCM Api was updated to v1, and now u can't pass `key=<API_KEY>` (once generated from FCM Console) header as before, now u should generate it by SDK `com.google.api-client` and there u should pass mystery SCOPES inside `createScoped()` method. [Here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/oauth2?authuser=0#googlecredential) is a lot of examples about it - without information about scopes. But what is this? where to get it? I can't to find any information about it. Please help me

Comment: scope from [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/auth-server?authuser=0): __To authorize access to FCM, request the scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging__ is INVALID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way of getting access token is not working I tried.But u can try a direct http request.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
       public final static String   AUTH_KEY_FCM    = "server key";
       public final static String   API_URL_FCM     = 
                                      "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";

    // Method to send Notifications from server to client end.

    // userDeviceIdKey is the device id you will query from your database

    String authKey = AUTH_KEY_FCM; // You FCM AUTH key
    String FMCurl = API_URL_FCM;

    URL url = new URL(FMCurl);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    conn.setUseCaches(false);
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.setDoOutput(true);

    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "key=" + authKey);
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    json.put("to",
            "Device key");
    JSONObject info = new JSONObject();
    info.put("title", "Demo"); // Notification title
    info.put("body", "Hello Test notification"); // Notification body
    json.put("notification", info);

    OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
    wr.write(json.toString());
    wr.flush();
    conn.getInputStream();

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((conn.getInputStream())));

    String output;
    System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
    while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(output);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: This is an old API (will be legacy soon), i was try to use v1 API

Answer (score 4):

The scope is list of String. I have tried several endpoints from https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes and worked.

1. "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase"
2. "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"
3. "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.readonly"

   ```
   val googleCredential = GoogleCredential.fromStream("yourjson.json")            
   .createScoped(Arrays.asList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase", 
   "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform", 
   "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.readonly"))
   googleCredential.refreshToken()
   return googleCredential.accessToken
   ```

Comment: The scope is list of String. 

[
                "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase",
                "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform",
                "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.readonly"
            ]

Answer (score 0):

Authorization Scopes is the list that I found on the page. At first I could not understand what they were for, but then I guessed

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages/send

Comment: Please include relevant portions from the link here